# how to run Chrome(Selenium) parallel to JavaFX

Tags: java, selenium, javafx

I use Chrome(Selenium) to parse website. And I use JavaFX.
I want to work with the interface and control the browser at the same time.
When I activate(launch) the browser(Selenium), interface(javaFX) stops responding.

I try to launch the browser in two ways: from main stream and parallel.
How to solve this problem?